# Do someone need to explicitly tell about their conversion to islam?

Tags: quran, hadith, nikah, conversion, other-religions

Assalamu alaikum,

I'am new to this community. Sorry for this personal question. I fell love with non muslim woman. After I convincing her and told about Islam and it's beautiful she ready to convert into islam. But she afraid of society. She doesn't want to know about her conversion to islam for a while. Due to society. Is it necessary to explicitly announcing her conversion? or Does she can be a good muslim without telling them to anyone?

Please give me your opinion.

Comment: You mean to say she doesn't want her family in friends to know about her conversion... and for how long she expects to keep it hidden?

Comment: @Sassir -  Thanks for the comment. Yeah she doesn't want to know about for a short period, until things get set. Roughly 1 to 2 years..

Comment: I don't know why nobody considered answering this :S but if you want to marry her you must clarify about her situation: Is she a Muslim by now or will she be a Muslim at the time of marriage or later? As the rulings of marriage play also a role. as to your title question it is answerable and I'd say the Qur'an already offers answers.

Comment: @Medi1Saif- thanks for your considerations. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Lets say that the "belief and choice" of the guardian for her marriage actually depends on the girls belief: A Christian needs a Christian Guradian (Father in first place), a convert needs a Muslim guardian if her guardian is non-Muslim she may choose a trustworthy Muslim for this task. A girl who is neither Muslim nor considered from among the people of the book can't get married to a Muslim.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah another option is to reveal the conversion to only the close relatives and community leaders and tell them the reason for not publicly declaring. This way you can get benefit of belonging to community when any situation arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to declare the faith, as it is important in many social matters. For example, in the event of death, if faith is not declared then Muslims will not be allowing funeral in Muslim grave yard. Also, this means she will have to hide any sign of being a Muslim and it can cause unnecessary hardships and may sometimes require her to stop praying or fasting just to avoid being seen by others.

But if there is real reason to hide faith like fear of being harmed by others, then this can be done. In Quran there is an instance of a person in the times of Musa(a.s) where he is mentioned as a person who concealed his belief.

> And a believing man from the family of Pharaoh who concealed his faith
>   said, "Do you kill a man [merely] because he says, 'My Lord is Allah '
>   while he has brought you clear proofs from your Lord? And if he should
>   be lying, then upon him is [the consequence of] his lie; but if he
>   should be truthful, there will strike you some of what he promises
>   you. Indeed, Allah does not guide one who is a transgressor and a
>   liar. [Quran 40:28](https://quran.com/40/28)

Answer (score 0):

It is not paramount for a new Muslim to announce it publicaly. She can decide to announce it when her situation become comfortable for her. She can be a good practicing Muslim without telling to her parents regarding her accepting Islam bcos Allah clearly mentioned in Holy Book QURAN that only those Muslim are nearer to ALLAH   who is pious and having good deeds.It is also good appourtunity for you that you can be able to get Sawab (reward from ALLAH) by converting a non Muslim under umbrella of great religion ISLAM and guide her the true path of ALLAH ALMIGHTY. ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give a proof from Quran and Hadith related to this problem?